# Maven Cannot Resolve a Dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

I am having a problem in my spring-boot project.

```
Cannot resolve com.didisoft:pgplib:3.1.2.1
```

This error is thrown when I am trying to import this dependency -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.didisoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>pgplib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I am checking

```
/.m2/repository/com/didisoft/pgplib/3.1.2.1/
```

folder,
all I've got are these two files

```
pgplib-3.1.2.1.jar.lastUpdated and pgplib-3.1.2.1.pom.lastUpdated
```

I have also tried adding a didisoft repository in my .m2/settings.xml, but it still didn't solve the problem

Comment: Drop us an email at our support email and we will check the logs of our maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to put your credencials in settings.xml according with this [instructions](https://www.didisoft.com/2017/01/17/maven-repository/)?

settings.xml

```
<servers>
<server>
        <id>didisoft-repository</id>
        <username>email address for accessing DidiSoft Customers section</username>
        <password>email address for accessing DidiSoft Customers section</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>didisoft-repository</id>
      <url>https://didisoft.com/repox/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.didisoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>pgplib</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Yes, of course I did. I followed those instructions to add Didisoft repository.

Comment: So, try to delete /.m2/repository/com/didisoft/pgplib folder to maven try to import again. Maybe it has corrupted.

Comment: Oh, I think you need to contact them to support.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try running `mvn clean install -U`?

```
$ mvn --help
...
-U,--update-snapshots        Forces a check for missing
                             releases and updated snapshots on
                             remote repositories
...
```

Comment: Sorry, but his is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JFMeier, I'm sorry. I don't have enough reputation to comment directly on the question. Hence, had to write an answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25877302)

Comment: @Boken, should we wait for the OP to confirm/deny if the solution worked?